# Giving an proof on a combinatorial statement

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Prove with a combinatorial argument that $\displaystyle\binom{a+b}{2}-\binom{a}{2}-\binom{b}{2}=ab.$

I'm assuming we can give a committee forming argument, but I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: A committee forming argument is absolutely one of the things you can think about doing.  Notice the different numbers involved... $a$, $b$, and $2$.  What sort of interpretation can you give the number $\binom{a}{2}$?  What about $\binom{a+b}{2}$?  (*Hint: men and women*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as $$\binom{a+b}{2}=\binom{a}{2}\binom{b}{0}+\binom{a}{1}\binom{b}{1}+\binom{a}{0}\binom{b}{2}$$ and note that both sides count the number of ways to choose a pair of people from $a$ men and $b$ women.  The left hand side is clear.  The right hand side performs the count according to three cases:

- $2$ men and $0$ women
- $1$ man and $1$ woman
- $0$ men and $2$ women

Comment: How would I exactly consider the ways of choosing a pair from $a$ men and $b$ women. Sorry if this seems obvious.

Comment: @FrostBite, I added more details.

Comment: thank you. I understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It’s easier to prove that $\binom{a+b}2=ab+\binom{a}2+\binom{b}2$. You have $a$ men and $b$ women, and you want to choose $2$ of them to represent the whole group. Find two different ways to compute the number of ways to choose the two representatives if their sexes don’t matter.